# Resolve Lucene LockObtainFailed Exception permanently (in Java)

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on project in Java that uses the Lucene Search (Simple Lucene Library not using Solar). When I run project, it get stuck and after some time it shows `org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out exception.`

The fastest and easy way to tackle this issue is to remove the `write.lock` file in lucene indexing folder and restarting the tomcat. But when I run my application it shows the same exception. I want permanent solution to this issue.

Please help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Getting that error is a clear sign of something awry in the way you handle `IndexReader` and `IndexWriter`s. You are probably opening more than one of them for the same directory. Instead of handling them directly you should use `NRTManager` or `SearcherManager`, which handle the reopening automatically according to the best practices.

Comment: Topolink Its not the  'IndexWriters' problem. I have closed and reopened it very carefully. Can you please tell me the other possible reasons that cause this exception to happen?

Comment: Well, do can you write a small example in code that reliably reproduces this? I am not aware of any Lucene bugs in this respect. It can also be platform-specific and directory implementation-specific. You can try to use a specific directory implementation instead of the default one.

Comment: Another *possibility* is that your app (process) opens only one writer, but you just happen to have more than one process running simultaneously...

Comment: Another possibility very similar to Topolink's thought, If you have only one open IndexWriter open, but then attempt to use IndexReader.delete.  Solution: Never use IndexReader.delete (if you are using v4, then this isn't the issue, as that method is gone, rather than just deprecated).

Comment: Also, if your application doesn't close correctly and fails to close the writer when exiting, then it can have this problem when you run it again, and it attempts to open one.  In that case you'll need to be sure your closing the application correctly, handling errors and exceptions correctly, and not exiting the process with a SIGKILL (kill -9).